# How many ways are there to calculate a method of moment estimator?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have $X_1,...,X_n$ iid random variables, where $X_i \sim \text{exponential}(\theta)$

We know $\Bbb E[X_i] = \frac{1}{\theta}$

**One Way To Calculate A Method of Moment**

Let $\Bbb E[X] = \bar{X}$. Then $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$

This is one MOM estimator.

**My Question**

Is there a second way to calculate method of moment estimators? If so, what is it and why are there two?

Comment: That seems right. But notice that the MOM estimator is biased. You may be thinking about modifying it to be unbiased. It might help if you can tell us why you think there might be a "second" way? What have you read or been told that raises the issue?

Comment: I was told I can find two distinct ones by my Econ professor. I'm a bit confused by it myself. Here's the prompt "Derive two different Method of Moments estimators for θ." I saw the TA and he said I should need to use the sample  $\Bbb E[X^2]$ somehow in the solution, but I don't really understand where to go with this despite googling a lot.

Comment: For $X \sim Exp(rate = \lambda)$ we have $SD(X) = E(X) = 1/\lambda$ and $V(X) = 1/\lambda^2.$ So you could set the sample variance $S^2$ equal to $1/\lambda^2$ and get a "sample-second-(central)- moment-equal-to-population-second-(central)-moment" estimator. However, there is only one parameter to estimate, and I'm not sure I'd call the one from second moments a proper MOM estimator. Definitions in econ may differ from those in math stat. Don't know. Anyhow, the estimator you mention in your Question works better.

Comment: Can you derive that for me? I am really not grasping the concept at all and it would really help me understand it.

Comment: If we set $S^2$ equal to $1/\lambda^2$ then $\hat \lambda = 1/S.$

Comment: Is that valid? I did that myself earlier but erased it because it didn't make sense to me. How can I use $S$? I thought the end result has to be in terms of $\bar{X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have data from the distribution $Exp(rate = \lambda).$
The Question mentions the estimator $\hat \lambda_1 = 1/\bar X$ and
a Comment mentions the estimator $\hat \lambda_2 = 1/S.$ (I use
$\lambda$ instead of $\theta$ because you are using a rate
parameter, and many people are used to using the letter $\lambda$ for that.)

A simple simulation in R compares the properties of these two estimators. We generate 100,000 samples to get an idea of their
relative performance.
Suppose the sample size is $n = 10$ and the rate is $\lambda = 1.$

```
m = 10^5;  n = 10;  lam = 1
x = rexp(m*n, lam)
DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # m x n matrix, each row a sample of size 10
a = rowMeans(DTA)        # vector of m sample means
s = apply(DTA, 1, sd)    # vector of m sample SDs
est.1 = 1/a              # vector of m est.1's  
mean(est.1);  sd(est.1)
## 1.110645  # aprx E(est.1); biased because > 1
## 0.3929144 # aprx SD(est.1)
est.2 = 1/s              # vector of m est.2's
mean(est.2);  sd(est.2)
## 1.282331  # aprx E(est.2); greater bias than est.1
## 0.5761103 # aprx SD(est.2); more variable than est.1
```

We hope that an estimator will be unbiased, and have a relatively
small variance. A simulation is not a proof, but one can show analytically what is suggested
by this simulation:

**Bias:**  The first estimator $\hat \lambda_1 = 1/\bar X$ is slightly biased because $E(\hat \lambda_1) \approx 1.1 > \lambda = 1.$
The second estimator $\hat \lambda_2 = 1/S$ has a larger bias because $E(\hat \lambda_2) \approx 1.3.$

**Variability:**  The second estimator has 
$SD(\hat \lambda_2) > SD(\hat \lambda_1).$

Thus the second estimator $\hat \lambda_2 = 1/S$ is worse than
$\hat \lambda_1 = 1/\bar X$ in both respects.

This is what I meant in my Comment when I said (vaguely) that the first estimator "works better" than the second.

**Note:** You asked if $\hat \lambda_2 = 1/S$ is 'valid.' As I said in
an earlier comment it is at least somewhat like a MOM estimator
because it is obtained by setting a population moment equal
to a sample moment and solving for the parameter in question.
But when there is only one parameter, the usual thing is to
use only first moments (means) for this. Certainly most
statisticians would say that $\hat \lambda = 1/\bar X$ is **the**
MOM estimator of $\lambda.$ Some might agree that $\hat \lambda_2 = 1/S$ is **a** MOM estimator, but most would wonder why you're
looking for a second MOM estimator.

Even if one agrees to call $\hat \lambda_2$ a MOM estimator,
it is easy to see it is not going to be used in practice because
it has such terrible properties.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much. what language is that code written in by the way?

Comment: In R, as mentioned. R is excellent, free software that works on Windows, Mac, and Unix computers. Easy to install from `www.r-project.org`. Official user manuals can be very technical in places, but there are lots of elementary help pages on the Internet.